# How do I work out energy stored in a capacitor bank?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, energy

I would like to know how to work out energy stored in a capacitor bank ?
I have done my own working outs and have reached an answer of 0.192J, I don't know if this is correct ?[image]

Comment: I think you're slightly off. Hint: If each Cb is 20 microfarads, what is the total equivalent capacitance of the bank of (Cb + Cb) // Cb? After that, it's merely a matter of applying the correct formula...

Comment: You forgot to divide by 2 i.e. E = \$\dfrac{CV^2}{2}\$

Answer (score 1):

Since W=0.5*C*V^2, you just have to find out the total capacitance of the three capacitors combined and apply the formula with the given Vb = 80V.

I have calculated a total capacitance of 30uF which gives me  a stored energy of 96mJ.

So, have a look if you calculated the equivalent capacitance correctly.

Comment: He probably missed the 0.5 in E = 0.5 x C x V^2

Comment: Thankyou guys, yeah I just forgot/missed out the 0.5 -_-